# Trying to get username in socket.io and emitting a message

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

Okay, So I half wat got it work the way I want. Here is my modified code:

```
//Route to game app
app.get('/game', function (req, res) {
  if (req.user) {
    res.render('game');

    // Socket stuff
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {

      var dataObj = {
        id: req.user.id,
        username: req.user.username,
      };
      socket.emit('startup', dataObj);
      console.log(dataObj.username);

      // Server Time
      var interval = setInterval(function () {
          var momentNow = moment();
          var data = momentNow.format('LT');
          socket.emit('time', data);
        }, 60000);

      // Chat - Needs work
      socket.on('chat', function (msg) {
        message = msg;
        io.emit('message', { message: message });
      });
    });
  } else {
    req.flash('error', 'You need to be signed in!');
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

I had to end up doing it this way, so my user tables could be defined in the socket.io part. Now the problem is this... It says undefined client-side:

```
socket.on('startup', function (dataObj) {
  console.log(dataObj.username);
});
```

It says user is undefined, but server side it is defined, why wouldn;t it transfer over like logic would dictate?

Comment: so what issue you are facing

Comment: Well the issue is, it is not grabbing the username of the one submitting the message. I understand why req.user.username doesn't work. However I can't seem to figure out how to grab the username and send it to the server-side, even though it is in the database and should be fairly easy

Answer (score 0):

Make change on server side

```
io.emit('message', {message: message, username : username }
```

and on the client

```
 socket.on('message',function(data) {
    // do something with data
       var message = data.message
       var name = data.username
 });
```

Comment: Try this, var username = (req.user.username !==null)? req.user.username : storedUsername

Comment: In place of  socket.emit('chat', msg, storedUsername); also write it in above format as socket.emit('chat', {msg: msg, storedUsername: storedUsername} ;

Comment: storedUsername also returns as undefined, well.. null. Because all I'm doing is var sotredUsername; at the start of my jQuery file. I'm trying to define a dataObj variable that carries all my data, but I can;t seem to get it to pick up anything that way as well.

Comment: Assign some string to sotredUsername in order to check whether it will still come null or what.

Comment: I edited the OP to show what I am trying to do now. Hopefully it is a bit more clear.

Comment: Why does everyone think it's acceptable to emit a message to hundreds of thousands of people and then let their clients filter out the message spam intended for one recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, on the client side:

```
$(function(){

var username =  prompt("Enter your name");
var userObj = {username: username}

$('#chat').load('chat.ejs', function () {
  $('button#test').click(function () {
    console.log('this is a test');
  });

  $('#chat-form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var msg = $('#m').val();
    console.log(msg);
    $('#m').val('');

    if (!connected || msg == '') {
      return false;
    }

    userObj.message = msg;

    socket.emit('chat', userObj);
  });

  // Populat chat
  socket.on('message', function (data) { 

    $('#messages').append($('<li>').html(data.username + ': ' + data.message));
  });
});
})
```

and on the server:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

var interval = setInterval(function () {
      var momentNow = moment();
      var data = momentNow.format('LT');
      socket.emit('time', data);
    }, 60000);

  // Chat - Needs work
  socket.on('chat', function (data) {  
    io.emit('message', data);
  });
});
```

Comment: While that would work, it is not what I am looking for. I have updated my OP to show it a little more clearly, and I got it to work a bit, just not on client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out, although I feel like this is a bit weird:

```
  var userObj = {
    id: req.user.id,
    username: req.user.username,
  };
  var dataObj = {
    id: userObj.id,
    username: userObj.username,
  };
```